# Dynamic dropdownlist problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get values from my database to populate a drop down list.

I have debugged the following function and it is bringing out the expected results but only storing the last one in the return value:

```
public static string GetAllPlacements(string placementLocation)
    {
        string returnVal = null;
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteContent"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " + placementLocation + " FROM Placements";
            using (var CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlCon))
            {
                using (var DR = CMD.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (DR.Read())
                    {
                        returnVal = DR[selectField].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

E.g. there are two results, London and Paris but "returnVal" is only storing Paris.

The I bind this data to the drop down list:

```
private void refreshLocation()
{
    ddlLocation.DataSource = Placements.GetAllPlacements("Placement_Location");
    ddlLocation.DataBind();

    ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Please Select --", "0"));
}
```

In the drop down list the option Paris appears like this:

```
P
A
R
I
S
```

Instead of this:

```
London
Paris
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `selectField` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change  GetAllPlacements to return for example List of string:

```
public static List<string> GetAllPlacements(string placementLocation)
    {
        string returnVal = new List<string>;
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteContent"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " + placementLocation + " FROM Placements";
            using (var CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlCon))
            {
                using (var DR = CMD.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (DR.Read())
                    {
                        returnVal.Add(DR[selectField].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```